# What does this symbol mean in the following equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

[image]

$\Psi = \Psi(\mathbf{F})$ is a function of **F**, and $\mathbf{F}$ is a matrix.

$\mathbf{R}$ is matrix; $\lambda, \mu$ is scalar; $J = \mathrm{det}(\mathbf{F})$

Comment: Looks like the variation

Comment: @polfosol Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations)?

Comment: Something like that. Although we are dealing with matrices...

Comment: $A:B:=\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$ is a standard notation for a scalar product on matrices. the $\delta F$-like symbol is often used by engineers or physicists, they call it infinitesimal or something like that and they calculate with it *formally* as though it was a matrix, but you have to know that they mean it as a symbol. (usually this helps keeping tensor calculus short)

Comment: @Max Thanks! I found its definition, and it's called [double-dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Double-dot_product), or in some literature just called **double product**. And for $\delta$, if I take an example of scalar version of acceleration, say $dv/dt = a$, then I do $dv/dt \cdot \delta t = a \cdot \delta t$, and I will get $\delta v$ -- an infinitesimal increment of velocity. Am I right?

Comment: In variational calculus, $δf$ is used to describe the variation of $f$. In other terms, this denotes a tangent or direction vector. $$δI[f]=\lim_{s\to0}\frac{I[f+s·δf]-I[f]}{s}$$ is the normal definition of a directional derivative in direction $δf$. Also denoted in other contexts as $\partial I(f;δf)$,...

Comment: @Jiang Yes, I think that's probably meant by this notation.

Comment: @LutzL I checked the literature of Calculus of Variations, and it does have $\delta$ symbol. But considering the context of that equation, I think **Max**'s answer is more appropriate. Anyway, thank you very much : )

Comment: @polfosol Calculus of Variations does have $\delta$ symbol. But considering the context of that equation, I think **Max**'s answer is more appropriate. But thank you very much : ) Now I got the knowledge of variation.

Comment: @Max Thank you very much : ) Considering the context of that equation, I think your answer is more appropriate. Can you put your comment as an **Answer**, so I can close this thread?

Comment: i just dont find the time. (just copy+paste would result in a very low quality answer.) if you want to close your question, you can turn my comments into your own answer if you like and accept it. i would give you +1 in that case.

Comment: @Max Well, I'm not in a hurry. So if you have time someday, you post your answer, and I will keep this thread open until that day. Just take your time : )